# application crashes at first strcat_s

Tags: c++, file, search, crash, strcat-s

I have tried both strcat and strcat_s, but they both crash. Does anyone know why this happens? I can't find the problem.

```
Crash: "Unhandled exception at 0x58636D2A (msvcr110d.dll)"
_Dst        0x00ea6b30  "C:\\Users\\Ruben\\Documents\\School\\" char *
_SizeInBytes    260                         unsigned int
_Src        0x0032ef64  "CKV"                   const char *
available       228                         unsigned int
p           0x00ea6b50  ""                  char *
```

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

extern "C"
{
    char* GetFilesInFolders(LPCWSTR filedir, char* path)
    {
        char* files = "";

        char DefChar = ' ';
        char* Streepje = "-";
        bool LastPoint = false;

        WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
        TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
        HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        DWORD dwError = 0;

        StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, filedir);
        hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
            return "";

        do
        {
            DWORD attributes = ffd.dwFileAttributes;
            LPCWSTR nm = ffd.cFileName;
            char name[260];
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,ffd.cFileName,-1, name,260,&DefChar, NULL);

            for (int i = 0; i <= 260; i++)
            {
                if (name[i] == '.')
                    LastPoint = true;
                else if (name[i] == ' ')
                    break;
            }

            if (LastPoint == true)
            {
                LastPoint = false;
                continue;
            }

            if (attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                char* newfiledir = "";
                char* newpath = path;
                char* add = "\\";
                char* extra = "*";
                strcat_s(newpath, sizeof(name), name);
                strcat_s(newpath, sizeof(add), add);
                puts(newpath);
                strcpy_s(newfiledir, sizeof(newpath) + 1, newpath);
                strcat_s(newfiledir, sizeof(extra) + 1, extra);
                puts(newfiledir);

                size_t origsize = strlen(newfiledir) + 1;
                const size_t newsize = 100;
                size_t convertedChars = 0;
                wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
                mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, newfiledir, _TRUNCATE);
                LPCWSTR dir = wcstring;
                GetFilesInFolders(dir, newpath);
            }
            else
            {
                char* file = path;
                strcat_s(file, sizeof(name), name);
                puts(file);
                strcat_s(files, sizeof(file), file);
                strcat_s(files, sizeof(Streepje), Streepje);
                puts(files);
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        FindClose(hFind);
        return files;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* path = "C:\\Users\\Ruben\\Documents\\School\\";
    char* filedir = "C:\\Users\\Ruben\\Documents\\School\\*";
    size_t origsize = strlen(filedir) + 1;
    const size_t newsize = 100;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, filedir, _TRUNCATE);
    LPCWSTR dir = wcstring;
    char* files = GetFilesInFolders(dir, path);
    return 0;
}
```

Extra info: I don't want to use boost or strings and I want to keep this in unicode (default).

Comment: is name empty??? Did you try valgrind yet?

Comment: Since `add` is a `char *`, `sizeof(add)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)` which is definitely not what you want. Bluntly, it seems like you simply don't understand how to use C-style strings at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't understand how variables are stored in memory or how pointers work. In your `_tmain()` you have `char * path` pointing to a constant string literal, which you pass into `GetFilesInFolders()`, where it gets modified. Compilers tend to allow `char *`s to point at constant strings for backward compatibility with old C programs. You cannot modify these. You cannot append to them. The compiler (generally) puts these in a read-only segment. That's one reason why you're getting an exception.

Your whole `GetFilesInFolders()` is wrong. And as DarkFalcon pointed out, you haven't allocated any space anywhere for `files`, you have it pointing to a constant string literal.

Get "The C++ Programming Language" and read chapter 5.

Answer (score 2):

You assign a `const char*` to `files`, then attempt to append to it.

```
char* files = "";
// ... 
strcat_s(files, sizeof(file), file);
```

You cannot modify a constant string literal.

I would recommend that you turn on compiler warnings and make sure to look at them. This would warn you about assigning a `const char*` to a `char*`. To fix it, you might have changed `files` to be `const`, which would then cause your `strcpy_s` to no longer compile.

Comment: Good catch that the destination is in read-only memory.  The insufficient size of the destination buffer is also a serious problem.

Comment: I have compiler warnings turned on AFAIK, and I don't get any error messages. Also both "files" and "file" are char*.